# How to fix sql-query which double the price of all goods sold last year in the concrete department. Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

The bottom line: I have 3 tables: sales, departments and products. Creation Code below:

```
CREATE TABLE dep
(
   id     NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   city   VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
   name   VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT dep_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- 

CREATE TABLE prod
(
   id      NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   price   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   name    VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT prod_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

--

CREATE TABLE sales
(
   time      DATE NOT NULL,
   dep_id    NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   prod_id   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   cost      NUMBER (10, 2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT sales_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (dep_id) REFERENCES dep (id),
   CONSTRAINT sales_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES prod (id)
);
```

Filling code:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
      INSERT INTO dep
           VALUES (i,
                   CASE
                      WHEN i <= 50 THEN 'town1'
                      ELSE 'town2'
                   END,
                      'dep'
                   || to_char (i));

      INSERT INTO prod
           VALUES (i,
                   i * 10,
                      'prod'
                   || to_char (i));
   END LOOP;

   FOR i IN 1 .. 1000 LOOP
      INSERT INTO sales
           VALUES (trunc (to_date ('01.01.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) + sys.DBMS_RANDOM.value (0, 0.99) - i,
                   mod (i, 100) + 1,
                   mod (i, 100) + 1,
                   i);
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

I need to implement a query: to double the price of all goods that were sold **last year** **in the 'dep10'** department.
Here's what I managed to give birth:

```
UPDATE prod
SET prod.price = prod.price*2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM prod
                JOIN sales ON prod.id = sales.prod_id
                JOIN dep ON sales.dep_id = dep.id
                WHERE (DATEPART(Year, sales.time) = DATEPART(Year,DATEADD(Month, -1, GETDATE()))) AND dep.name = 'dep10' );
```

But surprise - not working. Actually, I get stuck with an expression to fetch records from last year. Please tell me the options for implementing requests of this type? Is there a universal subquery for fetching records from last year? Didn't find working example for Oracle.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is good and it's great you're showing the create table statements and the code to fill the tables. You could have set up a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81dc162a21b9d4f6ab85fffbb903d9fb. But, anyway, you should have mentioned the error message you got (`ORA-00904: "DATEPART": invalid identifier`). Never just say "it didn't work".

Comment: I see...Next question will be better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is mainly that you are selecting another product in the subquery. Moreover, `DATEPART` is not an Oracle keyword.

```
UPDATE prod
SET price = price * 2
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM sales 
  WHERE sales.prod_id = prod.id
  AND EXTRACT(Year FROM sales.time) = EXTRACT(Year FROM SYSDATE) - 1
  AND sales.dep_id = (SELECT id FROM dep WHERE name = 'dep10')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Thorsten's query (which I'm upvoting), but it seems more natural to write this using `JOIN` and some other mechanisms:

```
UPDATE prod
    SET price = price * 2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM sales s JOIN
                   dep d
                   ON s.dep_id = d.id
              WHERE s.prod_id = p.id AND
                    d.name = 'dep10' AND
                    s.time >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'YEAR') - INTERVAL '1' YEAR AND
                    s.time < TRUNC(sysdate, 'YEAR)
             );
```

I think this formulation is more likely to use an index on `sales(prod_id, time, dep_id)`.

Comment: And which query will be executed faster, in real working conditions, if there is an index on sales table? Or the same time?

Comment: @YuryIvanov . . . It depends on the index.  You would need to try, but I would expect this to be faster with the specified index.